# Can't run ./bin/mahout due to the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory error

Tags: eclipse, maven, slf4j, mahout

I am trying to use Mahout and create vectors from text using lucene indexers following this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Creating+Vectors+from+Text

but when I run the command ./bin/mahout from the MAHOUT_HOME directory in cygwin I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.<clinit>(MahoutDriver.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

I know that this is a dependency problem on slf4j, but I don't know how I should solve it.

I have built mahout successfully using "mvn install" and all the tests work fine with no errors and also I am using Eclipse Indigo (Maven Built-in feature) for my project (create lucene indexer).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I apologize if I have in-correctly understood your problem.

Perhaps this problem could be solved by adding the following dependency to the pom.xml of the project where you are attempting to consume MAHOUT :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If there is a specific version of the sl4j you need, check the maven central repository for it with [this](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3a%22slf4j-api%22) search.

Comment: Nope, it is already a dependency of the project, as you'd expect. Or else the whole project would not compile to start.

Comment: Could you please dump the output of mvn dependency:tree ? Also, I was wondering if you could perform a simple test : what happens if you copy the sl4j.jar into the JDK_HOME/jre/lib ? I strongly suspect that it is this dependency. I am not familiar with MAHOUT but from what I have just read, the root cause of this problem is always sl4j-api.jar missing from classpath.

Comment: Also, another suggestion : If the ./bin/mahout is an editable script what output do you get when you add `echo $CLASSPATH` in it ? 

Also, what happens when in the cygwin prompt you do this : `export CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/path_to_sl4j-api.jar` and then execute ./bin/mahout ?

Comment: this happens when I export classpath before executing ./bin/mahout :
'SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ProgramDriver
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver
      ...'

Comment: @zghaf, it would be great if you could also try out the other suggestions I mentioned above ( copying the JAR to JDK_HOME/jre/lib , adding the `echo` statement inside /bin/mahout if the latter is an editable script and finally, setting the classpath inside the /bin/mahout script )

If possible could you please post relevant portions of the script ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal: I have tried all of them, none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are running some Mahout class without third-party classes that Mahout depends on in your classpath. Here it's slf4j logging facade. You can add JARs from this project to your classpath. Or you can make sure the script you run sets that for you. Or you can use the ".job" file built by Mahout with Maven that makes a JAR file with all dependencies packaged up.

Comment: I think I might have confused you with the "project". What I am trying to do is I have a project in Eclipse which I'm using lucene to create indexes from my documents. now that I have the indexes saved in a separate directory, I want to create the term vector from this indexes. So I wanted to use cygwin to run the ./bin/mahout command. can you please be more specific which classpath you are talking about and how I should use the .job file? Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that my problem was using jdk 7 with mahout 0.4. I changed it to jdk 6 and everything worked perfectly afterwards.